# Android Studio emulator doesn't launch the app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

The emulator successfully opens but without launching the app, despite all necessary components are installed. So, I have no idea how to fix this.

It writes:

12:52   Emulator: handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf

12:52   Emulator: added library vulkan-1.dll

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFseU.png)

Comment: Do you have an AMD Processor or Intel?

Comment: @DEX7RA  I have an intel processor

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a documentation for you, that should solve your problem finally:

[Solution Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944169/am-emulator-library-vulkan-1-dll-failed-for-handlecpuacceleration-2021/66944170#66944170)

If you have no Vulkan Driver, download, unzip and install it:

[Download Vulkan Driver for your System](https://workupload.com/file/8bNrSdFuF65)

I'll keep that documentation updated.

Comment: it just caused more mistakes

Comment: I made some edits on my post. That should help you! :) Let me know!

Comment: Thank you a lot! But, unfortunately, I think it may be connected with the IDE error of some SQLite files missing

Comment: What error are you getting? Some line of codes would be helpful :)

Comment: I edit the post above, download the driver. That are the missing files I guess.

Comment: There is no direct way shown to download the driver, only a manual with its description. I would be very thankful if you told me how to download it)

Comment: I changed the link to a direct link to download. Probably better for everyone.