# AM Emulator: Library vulkan-1.dll: failed for handleCPUAcceleration

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator, vulkan

The Emulator shows following error when you run it in Android Studio on Windows 10:

```
04-04-2021 
14:45 AM Emulator: handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf 
14:45 AM Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed 
14:45 AM Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed 
14:45 AM Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

New installation doesn't work. What to do? I show you below, don't panic. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PREPERATION**

Ensure that you have installed the newest Driver Package:

[Direct Download Vulkan Driver Package](https://workupload.com/file/8bNrSdFuF65) for Windows

[Direct Download MoltenVK (Vulkan Driver)](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK) for MacOS.

**FOR ANDROID 6 TILL <10**

If you’re using Android 6 and above but less than Android 10 in Emulator then Re-Create the Emulator and Select Software – GLES 2.0 in the Emulated Performance while creating the AVD (or edit existing AVD).

[image: Change to GLES 2.0]

**FOR ANDROID 10+**

In Android 10 and higher, you are not able to change the **Emulated Performance** (Graphics) as you can see below:

[image: Can't change Graphics]

Therefore you need to edit the `config.ini` file of your **AVD**. Type the following path into your Windows Explorer:

```
C:/Users/<pc_name>/.android/avd/<AVD-device>/config.ini
```

Note that `<pc_name>` needs to replaced with your computer name and for `<AVD-device>` you need to place the name of your created device. In my case `Nexus_5X_API_24.avd`

Now edit the mentioned file and change to attributes as shown below:

```
hw.gpu.enabled=no
hw.gpu.mode=off
```

Now safe your changes. Remember to edit the file only if `Android studio` is closed to make changes apply at starting the software.

Thank you for reading! I keep this post updated as always. Cheers! :)