# Android Emulator can not start after update to macOS Big Sur 11.3 today

Tags: android-studio

I updated today the macOS to Big Sur 11.3, the android emulator can not work any more:

My Computer: Macbook Pro 2019

Android Studio Version: 4.1.3

Android Simulator Version: 30.5.5

Message: `The emulator process for AVD xxx was killed.`

I tried reinstall the android studio and restart, but the error is still the same. I can not start the android Emulator... :(

Error is here, It somehow related to `GLDirectMem/Vulkan`:

[image]

[image]

Do you have idea, how to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error occurs because Apple has made changes to the hypervisor entitlements. What you want to do is:

1. Use `/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64` as the directory for `qemu`
2. Add the entitlement to the `qemu-system-x86_64` binary by:

   - First create an xml file named `entitlements.xml` (does not matter where) with this content:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
   "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>com.apple.security.hypervisor</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```

   - Then sign the `qemu` binary with it:

   ```sh
   codesign -s - --entitlements entitlements.xml --force /Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
   ```

For more context, refer [here](https://www.arthurkoziel.com/qemu-on-macos-big-sur/)

Comment: I am very confused, this problem I just got after the update to the latest version. Before the update everything was fine util yesterday. However, the solution link you showed me is already nearly 5 months ago... Somehow, my time is slower than the author 5 months...

Answer (score 4):

**Check 1:**

If you have a Docker installed, stop that. It interrupt the emulator.

**Check 2:**

Try to launch your emulator from the command line, type:

1. `cd $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`
2. `tools/emulator -list-avds`
3. `tools/emulator @name_of_avd -verbose`

The `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment value should point to the android `SDK` location. You can find this in android studio under the `menu tools` -> `sdk manager`.

**Check 3:**

1. Delete all AVD's that you currently have.
2. Go to `Preferences` >> `Android SDK` >> `SDK Tools`
3. Uninstall `Android Emulator`
4. Restart `Android Studio`
5. Re-install `Android Emulator` from the same place.
6. And finally create a new emulator

**Sidenote:**

I made a [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932346/facing-android-studio-emulator-error-with-amd-cpu-2021) for AMD processors facing emulator issue on `Windows` systems.
Probably something from there could help also. Give it a shot and let me know if it worked. Cheers!

PS: Make sure you installed the latest `Vulkan` driver for `MacOS` (Intel CPU)
Download the driver from my other Intel [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944169/am-emulator-library-vulkan-1-dll-failed-for-handlecpuacceleration) or try this usefull [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483370/android-emulator-error-message-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-x86) I found.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but what is vulkan? How can I install it?

Comment: I tried to start from console, it reported missing the emulator engine for x86 cpu: ```emulator:Looking for emulator-x86 to emulate 'x86' CPU
emulator:Probing program: /Users/yinggu/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86
emulator:Probing program: /Users/yinggu/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator-x86
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.```

Comment: Alright now I know what the problem is. Your Macbook uses an Intel CPU and the acceleration is missing for the Emulator. Please download the vulkan driver from my Link under "PS:" in my answer. Did you tried the written "Checks" before?

Comment: I added another Link for macOS I found. Now you should definetely get the problem fixed. :)

Comment: I did the all the check 1, 2, 3. Just finished the check 3. After reinstall emulator, it is the same error, so i think, I should install the vulkan as you suggested. Will do it now. :D

Comment: I just tried to install the MoltenVK, but too many steps to follow... need to figure out. For short I followed @Mayokun suggestion, solved this problem. Anyway, thanks so much for the help! I think, the installation of the Vulkan should be also a solution. *^_^*

Comment: You are welcome. Glad that Mayokun and I could help you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Update your emulator to get rid of this issue.

Follow the steps below:

In your android studio go to SDK Manager -> SDK Tools Tab

Select Android Emulator and update it
OR

Uncheck Android Emulator and apply
Check Android Emulator and apply
If you want to stay with the Android Emulator version below 30.5.6 you can follow the steps mentioned in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288329/android-device-manager-fails-to-launch-after-updating-to-macos-big-sur-11-3/67288845#67288845)

Answer (score 1):

30.5.6 is out and it works fine. Apparently there has been any incompatibility between 30.5.5 and previous with Big Sur 11.3.